# How can I resize my MLMultiArray to fit my camera texture size?

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, semantic-segmentation, apple-vision

I am doing some semantic segmentation of people using DeepLabV3 mlmodel. The output after prediction is 513*513 as an MLMultiArray. Currently I am resizing my camera output to this size to apply the segmented array.

How can I resize the MLMultiArray to match my camera texture size?

```
if let observations = request.results as? [VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation],
        let segmentationmap = observations.first?.featureValue.multiArrayValue {
        
        // row - 513, col - 513
        guard let row = segmentationmap.shape[0] as? Int,
            let col = segmentationmap.shape[1] as? Int else {
                return
        }
}
```

Comment: If you can refer me to such learning materials, I can use them too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some demo code for using DeepLab V3 in an iOS app: https://github.com/hollance/SemanticSegmentationMetalDemo

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I had completed till segmentation part and was struggling with texture heights, Thanks a lot.